# Does Torturous Grounds prevent Cull the Weak

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

Cull the Weak increased damaged on slowed enemies, but Torturous Grounds causes the first two seconds of Caltrops to be an immobilize effect.

Does this override the slow for the first two seconds and thus not grant the extra damage?

Comment: Not sure if this is DH specific, if so can you add the class tag too - I am only guessing based on 'caltrops' mention

Comment: It is indeed, I've updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cull the Weak **will work** with Torturous Ground.

Tho i'm not sure why or how it works with other immobilize effects:

- All immobilize effects could count as 100% slow.
- It could be that Torturous Ground adds immobilize along with slow.
- Or Blizzard just made those 2 skills compatible.

More discussions [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149535849) and [there](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4209931756)